# GetFiles: Wrong result

Tags: .net, io

I'm using the following code in a recursive call:

```
var files = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

di is a DirectoryInfo that is passed in to the function. Assume a file tiger.jpg in the root of some drive k. Occasionally, the result is not k:\tiger.jpg but k:\iger.jpg. I have no idea why or how. Has anyone ever had the same behavior?

**Edit 1**: It seems to occur even with directory names, because the recursive function does not list images in a subdirectory. I think it is mostly FAT ( because it usually reads from media such as SD card or USB sticks, sometimes from a DVD or CD ).

The fullname of each returned FileInfo object is signalled using an event. The recipient creates a new object that takes the path as an argument to the constructor. The constructor then calls a method that uses the path for getting information about the jpeg files:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open ( this.Path, FileMode.Open );
Image img = Image.FromStream ( fs, false, false );
```

This is where the exception occurs. As I get the files from a call to a framework component, I do not explicitly check again if they exist - I can build this into the system, but that does not solve my problem.

One thing I forgot: This does not happen on our test systems, but on a system round the globe :(

Comment: very strange...you sure you're not some weird string processing on the filename?

Comment: What can you tell us about when this happens? Is it only on root directories? Is it only on FAT filesystems? Is it always the same files that have the problems?

Comment: Show the code where you check recieved file names.

Comment: Does it always happen on the same filenames? Or on the same files everytime you run it?

Comment: On the sample it occurs on every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, it seems it was a specific combination of hardware that triggered some weird behavior. *The Win32 API brought up correct results while the .NET API returned wrong results.*

This wasn't reproducible on all installations. The only obvious difference were localization settings, but even changing them on a functional didn't helped us coming up with a repro on one of our local machines. As a new hardware revision will be rolled out there are no further investigations.

If you're sure you have covered all proposals from the other answers and have the very same problem, you might want to contact the OS vendor.

Answer (score 3):

Could be the wrong straw, but have you tried escaping the `\`.

In your example of `k:\tiger.jpg` C# will read the `\t` as a tab. This shouldn't really happen, but I have seen it occur. Try writing it so that all backslashes are replaced with `\\`

Comment: I ectually unescaped in my writing. The filenames are returned by the GetFiles method. No path is actually coded or entered manually.

Answer (score 1):

Antivirus can sometimes come into play here.  If you have one process generating the file and one process that is using it, you may have a race condition.

Rather than checking for the files existence, call the File.Open and then try/catch for an `IOException`.  You will need to then check what's happening when you hit the exception.

You can never assume that a file exists.

As for why you are losing a letter of the file name, how are you generating `this.Path`?

Comment: The files are on an external medium. Once inserted they are read using the GetFiles method - hence, the path is returned from a framework method I trust(ed) to list the correct file names.

Comment: Antivirus is an option I will check.